# Disable Visual Studio tabs from following website navigation VS 2022 Community

Tags: visual-studio

I've searched but haven't found a solution.  After a break, I've come back to a website project and when I run the website in IIS, VS tabs follow my website navigation.  For example: I go to my login screen and VS opens a tab displaying the HTML for my login page. Then when I go to the home page, VS opens a tab for the HTML in my home page.  And so on.  Needless to say, I didn't want to view the code for either login or home page. In fact, I had the code that I wanted to work on open already.  Thanks but, no thanks VS.  Can someone tell me how to disable this behavior?

I looked through tools/settings but I don't even know what setting I should be looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in the debugger and have breakpoints in the login and home pages?

Comment: No, it follows me on every page.  I just used those as examples.  If I go to anyrandom.aspx it opens a tab in the IDE showing the .aspx code for that page.  So for example:  I launch website in IIS and it starts on page1.aspx, the code for page1.aspx opens in VS, then I go to page2.aspx and the code for page2.aspx opens in VS.  If I go 10 pages deep in the website, I have 10 code pages automatically opened in VS.  So instead of staying on the code page I had open for say... page6.aspx, the code pages follow me as I navigate the site.  No breakpoints set.  It's weird.

Comment: I upvoted your answer to yourself. That's new to me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit!  I'll leave this here in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Under Tools->Options->Web Live Preview->General->Browser Link->Enabled,
set to False.

[image]